# How do we use perfect tense in passive voice?

Tags: grammar, tense, perfect-tense, preterite, passive

Was wird am meisten gebraucht in der Passivform der Vergangenheit? Präteritum oder Perfekt?

Perfekt habe ich noch nie gehört im mündlichen Gebrauch. Oder habe ich nicht gut aufgepasst?
Also, was wird am meisten gebraucht?

> Die Polizei wurde von den Nachbarn angerufen.

oder

> Die Polizei ist von den Nachbarn angerufen worden.

Comment: Das ist wohl regional ganz unterschiedlich und kommt wahrscheinlich auf das Sprachgefühl des Einzelnen an.

Comment: Persönliche Einschätzung: schriftlich würde ich die erste, mündlich die zweite Form benutzen. Tatsächlich dürfte aber die aktive Form im Perfekt die häufigste sein, aber das war ja nicht die Frage: "Die Nachbarn haben die Polizei gerufen."

Answer (score 4):

Im gesprochenen Deutsch wird im Grunde kein Imperfekt verwendet, das **Perfekt ist da das allgemeine Vergangenheitstempus.**

Andererseits vermeidet man im Gesprochenen auch gerne das Passiv, es ist eher Schriftdeutsch  mit Anklängen von "Behördendeutsch". Was macht ein Sprecher stattdessen?

**Aktiv**, wenn derjenige "Täter", der etwas tut, wichtig ist (die Nachbarn)

> Die Nachbarn haben die Polizei gerufen.

**Unpersönliches** *man*/ *einer* /*jemand*, wenn der Täter irrelevant ist

> Später hat jemand die Polizei gerufen.

In geschriebenem, **literarischem Deutsch ist das Imperfekt die Erzählzeit**. Dort müsste stehen

> Die Polizei wurde ... gerufen.

Die Kombination Vergangenheit+Passiv triffst du mündlich aber eher selten an, und wenn, dann würde ich wie üblich Perfekt wählen.