# Konjunktiv 1 and 2

Tags: subjunctive, passive, perfect-tense

I have the grasp of both konjunktivs but there are still a few questions I have surrounding the topic:

In Konjunktiv 1, I've seen:

"Er sagte, er hätte einen Hund"

However, LEO gives no conditional form for konjunktiv 1, just present and perfect, so I don't know how it's used.

Also, in konjunktiv 2 I've seen sometimes würde with haben at the end, but sometimes just hätte. Is there any difference and does this apply to all verbs?

I know this has nothing to do with the konjunktiv but I'm also lost when it comes to the past tense in the passive voice, with it sometimes being used with wurde and sometimes with worden. I've found that wurde is imperfekt and worden perfekt but I want to know if these are both used as interchangeably as it normally is in active voice.

Comment: On the *wurde* (preterite) versus *worden* (perfect) in German: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/7293/. On verbs whose subjunctive 2 form is actually used: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/22604.

Comment: Furthermore, you are asking three questions only mildly related by the subject. Imho, this is too broad. Please narrow it down to one.

Comment: (not native speaker) There is no conditional form of konjunktiv 1. Instead, you could consider konjunktiv 1 as a "lighter form" of konjunktiv 2. I considered it always as a beautiful "syntax sugar" in the language, this may be the reason, why is it not very well supported by the other parts of the "framework".

Answer (score 4):

**Konjuktiv I** is used for indirect speech:

Please note **haben** is a tricky word because it can be both a full verb (meaning: *besitzen – to possess*) and an auxiliary. Let's use *besitzen* instead:

> Er sagte, er **habe** einen Hund. *(Konjunktiv I Präsens)*
>
> Er sagte, er **besitze** einen Hund. *(Konjunktiv I Präsens)*
>
> Er sagte, er **habe** einen Hund gehabt.  *(Konjunktiv I Perfekt)*
>
> Er sagte, er **habe** einen Hund besessen.  *(Konjunktiv I Perfekt)*

You can also build other tenses but as they are straightforward, grammars do not list them:

> Er sagte, er **werde** einmal einen Hund besitzen. *(Konjunktiv I Futur I)*

Putting conditionals into indirect speech calls for *Konjunktiv II* instead.

> Er sagte, er **besäße** einen Hund, **läge** seine Wohnung nicht im vierten Stock. *(Konjunktiv II Präsens)*

It's not possible to tell apart indirect speech conditionals from bare conditionals. *Konjunktiv II* ruled conditionals are reporting from a talk to the inner self.

> Er **besäße** gerne einen Hund, **läge** seine Wohnung nicht im vierten Stock. *(Konjunktiv II Präsens)*

---

**About using würden**: This is a general replacement for using genuine *Konjunktiv* forms and may be used **anytime**. It is the preferred way to express the *Konjunktiv* mood if the *Konjunktiv* form of a verb isn't different from the *Indikativ* form, which happens often. Another way to get around that limitation is using the *Konjunktiv II* form instead but the latter is only allowed for that reason, not as a general replacement.

> Wir lügen nicht. *(Indikativ I Präsens)*
>
> Wir sagten, wir **lügen** nicht. *(Konjunktiv I Präsens – indistiguishable from Indikativ)*
>
> Wir sagten, wir **würden** nicht lügen. *(Konjunktiv I Präsens – würden replacement)*
>
> Wir sagten, wir **lögen** nicht. *(Konjunktiv II Präsens – replaces Konjunktiv I)*

---

Please open a new question to discuss your passive voice problems.

Comment: So, if it is the case that you use Präsens and Perfekt, is it possible to use Imperfekt as well

Comment: German has no imperfect tense; because it has the same meaning as *Perfekt*, it's called *Präteritum*. And yes, Präteritum can be set in Konjunktiv as well, but the forms for Konjunktiv I Präteritum and Konjunktiv II Präsens are indistinguishable. Some grammars even say Konjunktiv II is the Präteritum of Konjunktiv I, but if you say that the difference between tense and mood vanishes.

Comment: I have seen that being said in some places. So, are you suggesting it's best to avoid the Präteritum when using Konjunktiv 1?

Comment: No? They can be told apart by their use. *Konjunktiv I* is used for indirect speech, *Konjunktiv II* for uncertainty and conditionals.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. So, is the Präteritum as it usually is e.g. haben = hatten and sein = waren, because I've seen hätte being used to mean had in some examples of using konjunktiv 1.

Comment: No, for past tense indirect speech you should use the *Perfekt* forms. Northern speakers may differ and use *Konjunktiv II* forms for some common verbs instead – those where they would use *Präteritum* in speech instead of the common *Perfekt*.

Comment: Right okay, I think I understand now, and I assume that the conditional in konjunktiv 1 follows the same pattern as werden i.e. du würdest, er würde etc.