# Using the konjunktiv II to express uncertainty

Tags: subjunctive

A native speaker corrected me when I used this sentence:

> Vielleicht hätte sie einen schlechten Tag.

to this sentence:

> Vielleicht hatte sie einen schlechten Tag.

Now my understanding was that subjunctive II is used when the statement is one of uncertainty, as stated by Janka [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40788/konjunktiv-1-and-2#comment100612_40790).
The statement does speak in an uncertain mood, so why is the subjunctive incorrect to use here?

Comment: This certainly depends on context - we could construct an example where the first version is correct. The second version occurs a lot more frequently, however.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### The subjunctive does not express or accompany uncertainty

This is a common myth is perpetuated by teachers, grammar books, etc. calling the subjunctive *Möglichkeitsform* or similar. I will try to briefly explain why this is a myth, where it comes from, and what grain of truth it holds.

What the subjunctive does is mainly this:

1. The subjunctive I expresses indirect speech and similar. Roughly, whenever you could put something into quotes, you can instead use the subjunctive I.
2. The subjunctive II expresses that something is counterfactual, usually a part of a conditional statement (irrealis).
3. Both subjunctives are used in fixed and somewhat archaic expressions, most prominently the subjunctive II for politeness and the subjunctive I for “imperatives to the third person”.
4. For the modal verbs *können, sollen, dürfen, müssen,* and *mögen,* the subjunctive leads to weird and potentially complete changes of meaning, sometimes adding the notion of uncertainty. For example, *dürfen* in the indicative mood means *to be allowed to,* but in the subjuntive II mood, it can **also** mean *to probably be.*

In none of these cases does the subjunctive simply add the notion of uncertainty. In Case 2 it goes further and expresses impossibility instead of possibility; in Case 4, it does something on top of it; in Cases 1 and 3, it does something different altogether.

However, in most applications whatever is described is somehow vaguely associated with uncertainty: For example, we usually are not certain about reported statements, and if we have to politely ask for something, it may or may not happen. But then again, this also holds for the imperative or the future tense and nobody claims that those express uncertainty.

[Belles Lettres](https://www.belleslettres.eu/content/konjunktiv/konjunktiv-optativ-potentialis.php) treated this subject more extensively (in German), but somewhat prescriptively.

#### How to express uncertainty

The best and most clear way to express uncertainty in German are adverbs like *vielleicht, möglicherweise,* or *wahrscheinlich* (without any particular mood). Thus your second example is correct:

> Vielleicht hatte sie einen schlechten Tag.

You can also use modal verbs like *sollen, dürfen,* and *müssen* in the subjunctive II mood and *können* in all moods, but beware of other potential meanings.

Comment: Why *impossibility* instead of *irreality* or *counterfactuality* for 2.?

Comment: @DavidVogt: Because it is easier to grasp and nicely contrasts with *possibility* (which was not used here). See my edit.

Comment: You say yourself that (im)possibility is not the domain of the subjunctive. It contrasts with the indicative in that it says that something isn't the case, though it conceivably might be the case. Possibility and factuality are separate dimensions. An example: *Sie können nicht nach Hause gehen (bevor die Arbeit erledigt ist)* (factual impossibility), *Sie würden nach Hause gehen können (wenn die Arbeit erledigt wäre)* (counterfactual possibility).

Comment: There are much weirder pragmatic usages of Konjunktiv II in Austrian German. Craftsman ringing at your door: "Grüß Gott, ich wäre wegen der Heizung da."

Comment: And also, you can use the "future" to express an assumption you believe to be true: _Sie wird einen schlechten Tag gehabt haben_.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Your distinction between *possibility* and *factuality* is either artificial or needs much further explanation and a clear definition of terms, because their everyday definition does not suffice. Almost everything “might conceivably the case”. From context it should become clear that I use *possibility* to talk about probability and not about options and ability. However, the subjunctive expresses neither of the things covered by the broad umbrella of *possibility.* It can only express impossibility in some sense (I did not claim that it couldn’t).

Comment: @phipsgabler: In neither case did I claim to be exhaustive, though the craftsman example is probably a weird case of the subjunctive of politeness.

Comment: Well here's how I see it. 1. *Ich lese gerade* = "factual", it is a fact that reading is taking place. 2. *Ich kann lesen* = it is a fact that the ability is present. 3. *Wenn du die Anleitung lesen würdest* = "counterfactual", (i) the addressee is not in fact reading the manual (ii) the statement *you are reading the manual* could be true ("conceivably"). 4. *Wenn du lesen könntest* = "counterfactual", (i) the addressee does not have the ability to read, (ii) him having the ability is conceivable (*you can read* could be true).

Comment: I still don't understand your sentence *In Case 2 it goes further [than uncertainty] and expresses impossibility instead of possibility* (and what the subjunctive has to do with impossibility).

Comment: In case I haven't expressed this well: *Impossibility* strikes me as wrong because the term is needed for, for instance, *ich kann nicht lesen*: as long as that statement is true, *ich lese* must always be false, i.e. it cannot possible be true. *Wenn ich das gelesen hätte* does not portray reading as not having been possible, but merely as not having taken place *while being possible*.

Comment: @DavidVogt: *(Im)possibility* can be about probability or option; it never is about ability per se. I get where you are coming from if you interpret *(im)possibility* as strictly being about options. However, I use it to talk about probabilities which I hope to be clear from context.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft That is not what I am talking about. The double meaning of *können* is unfortunate, but not relevant. The truth of *X cannot do Y* implies that *X does Y* cannot be true **under any circumstances**, regardless of whether we are talking about possibility or ability. This implication is the essence of "impossibility": Not true under any circumstances. The truth of *if X had happened* merely implies that X didn't happen, but not that *X* was impossible (and not improbable, either). Also I don't understand the meaning of probability here – what's the likelihood of me reading a manual?